# c++ program stop working while running

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list

Please help to solve this.
This is simple data structure program
In this program firstly user input how many records he wants to enter then he enter record. After entering record he input for search and search data. now i make only one input for search No2. after that i will make others.
  when I run it and reach on search function it stop working and close with windows error.

[image]
Secondly while input data first time it not take input for name when loop run first time than it take input for name.

[image]

please help thanks in advance.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<cctype>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool check = true;
struct node    //structure of node //
{
    char name[20];
    char ccode[20];
    int marks;
    float cgpa;
    node *next;
}*head,*lastptr;

void add()    //Adds record of student//
{
    node *p;
    p=new node;
    cout<<"Enter name of student:"<<endl;
    gets(p->name);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter cource code:"<<endl;
    gets(p->ccode);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter Marks of student:"<<endl;
    cin>>p->marks;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Enter CGPA of student:"<<endl;
    cin>>p->cgpa;
    fflush(stdin);
    p->next=NULL;

    if(check)
    {
        head = p;
        lastptr = p;
        check = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lastptr->next=p;
        lastptr=p;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Student's information saved Successfully";
    getch();
}

void search()   //searches record of student//
{
    node *prev=NULL;
    node *current=NULL;
    char c_code[20];
    cout<<"Enter Roll Number to search:"<<endl;
    //c_code=getch();
    gets(c_code);
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"hkjhk"<<c_code;
    prev=head;
    current=head;
    while(current->ccode!=c_code)
    {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
    }
    cout<<"\nname: ";
    puts(current->name);
    cout<<"\n Cource Code:";
    cout<<current->ccode;
    cout<<"\nMarks:";
    cout<<current->marks;
    cout<<"\nCGPA:";
    cout<<current->cgpa;
    getch();
}


int main()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"How many students you want to enter"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    while(x>0){
        add();
        x--;
    }

    cout<<"\nwhat type of search you want to search select choice 1 ,2 3 \n";
    int choice;
    cout<<"1 search all student by cource code \n";
    cout<<"2 search all student by marks \n";
    cout<<"3 search all student by cgpa \n"; 
    cin>>choice; 
    if(choice==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        add();
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        cout<<"fhghgf";
        system("cls");
        search();
    }
    else
    {
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Run it in the debugger, find out where the crash is.

Comment: It's probably an uncaught exception or null pointer. You can probably dig the crash report out of your application data folders, but I agree the best thing to do is run under a debugger instead. (Which I guess you don't have installed since it didn't offer you the debug option on the 'stopped working' dialog? You can e.g. get Visual Studio Community for free.)

Comment: how can i run on debugger

Comment: i am using dev c++ editor and dont know about debugger please help me about that

Comment: I don't know Dev C++ but it looks like a wrapper around gcc and gdb. It sounds like there should be a 'Debug' tab at the bottom of the screen and a 'Debug' menu at the top?

Comment: Why are you mixing input methods like `cin` and `getch` and `fflush`?  Are you learning C++?  Is this what someone is _teaching_ you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `search()` method there is the loop:

```
while(current->ccode!=c_code)
{
   prev=current;
   current=current->next;
}
```

what happened when the code not found? You continue after the end of linked list.
in addition, you need compare the content, not the address, therefore you must use `strcmp`.

to solve the problem it should be:

```
while(current && strcmp (current->ccode, c_code))
{
   prev=current;
   current=current->next;
}
```

Another issue is the `gets()` method. you must `fflush(stdin)` **BEFORE** the `gets()` otherwise some `gets()` will read only a previous input's unreaden CR (end of line).

if you want instead of `fflush(stdin)` you may use some eatwhites method, like this:

```
istream& eatwhites(istream& stream)
{
    // to define white spaces manually:
    //const string skip=" \t\r\n";
    //while(string::npos != skip.find(stream.peek())){
    //   stream.ignore();
    //}

    //or just use isspace:
    while(isspace(stream.peek())){
        stream.ignore();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

and call it before `gets()`: `eatwhites(stdin);`
This method skip the white characters and place the read in the beginning of the data so you won't read an empty line left by the previous input...

another thing: you better use `std::getline();` and work with `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: it is working now but show only one record if tow students with same course code then it will stop working after showing 1stttt

Answer (score 1):

GDB could be useful to get the error. Launch GDB and run your program through the GDB console, perform the same actions in your program to get the failure and once the program fails, introduce the command "bt", it will report a backtrace about the latests executed lines till the failure, so you will be able to locate the error

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is in below line:

```
while(current->ccode!=c_code)
```

You will need to use:

```
while (strcmp (current->ccode, c_code))
```